# NodeJS html-pdf cutting of right side

Tags: css, node.js, html-pdf

I'm converting HTML to pdf using `html-pdf`; however, it is cutting the right side of the content. I grab the HTML from database and send a pdf response to the browser using express.

```
let htmlData = await getData(); // it returns the HTML below

pdf.create(htmlData ).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Length': buffer.length
    });
    return res.end(buffer);
});
```

The HTML content (I can't change it, but I can add css style if needed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      </style>
      <link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aguafina+Script|Alex+Brush|Bilbo|Condiment|Great+Vibes|Herr+Von+Muellerhoff|Kristi|Meddon|Monsieur+La+Doulaise|Norican|Nothing+You+Could+Do|Parisienne|Permanent+Marker|Sacramento|Yellowtail\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      \n<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"font-size: 12pt;\"><strong>My Doc TEST</strong></span></p>\n<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"font-size: 8pt;\"><strong>dksfdksfndskfndsklfndskl dfkdsfnldks dsfkljdsklfdsmlkf.</strong></span></p>\n<p style=\"text-align: left;\"><span style=\"font-size: 8pt;\">Date: <strong>08/19/2020</strong></span></p>\n<table style=\"height: 30px;\" width=\"993\">\n
      <tbody>
         \n<tr style=\"height: 5847px;\">\n<td style=\"width: 488.5px; height: 5847px;\">\n
         <p><span style=\"background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff; font-size: 8pt;\">Moving In &mdash; General Information</span></p>
         \n
         <ol>
         \n
         <li dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000; font-size: 8pt;\">Parties. This Lease Contract (&ldquo;Lease&rdquo;) is between you, the resident(s) (list all people signing the Lease): ________<strong>NAME</strong> <strong>NAME</strong> ____<strong>NAME NAME </strong>_____________________________ _________________________________________________________________ _________________________________________________________________ _________________________________________________________________ and us, the owner:&nbsp;<strong>COMPANY ABCABCABC</strong> You are renting Apartment No<strong> 53, </strong>at<strong> 123 MAIN </strong>in<strong> MY CITY</strong>, <strong>AA</strong> <strong>00000</strong> for use as a private residence only. The terms &ldquo;you&rdquo; and &ldquo;your&rdquo; refer to all residents listed above or, in the event of a sole resident&rsquo;s death, to someone authorized to act for the estate. The terms &ldquo;we,&rdquo; &ldquo;us,&rdquo; and &ldquo;our&rdquo; refer to the owner listed above and not to property managers or anyone else. Neither we nor any of our representatives have made any oral promises, representations, or agreements. This Lease is the entire agreement between you and us.</span></li>
         \n
         <li dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000; font-size: 8pt;\">Occupants. The apartment will be occupied only by you and (list all other occupants not signing the Lease): _________________________________________________________________ _________________________________________________________________ _________________________________________________________________ _________________________________________________________________&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; and no one else. Anyone not listed here cannot stay in the apartment for more than ___7____ consecutive days without our prior written consent, and no more than twice that many days in any one month. If the previous space isn&rsquo;t filled in, 2 days total per month will be the limit.
   </body>
</html>
```

The PDF shows:
[image]

If I change to just return the HTML content, it displays everything:
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the issue with the following CSS properties:

```
break-inside: auto
```

The break-inside CSS property sets how page, column, or region breaks should behave inside a generated box. If there is no generated box, the property is ignored. Auto allows, but does not force, any break (page, column, or region) to be inserted within the principal box.

And if you changed the following property from its normal state, you need to change it back:

```
white-space: normal
```

Normal: Sequences of white space are collapsed. Newline characters in the source are handled the same as other white space. Lines are broken as necessary to fill line boxes.